# Symfony2 ecommerce bundles feedback

Tags: symfony, e-commerce

I'll shortly begin the development of an ecommerce site based on Symfony2. I'll use Symfony2 for those main reasons:

- I happen to know and like this framework
- The customer need is not a typical webstore, so webshops like Magento are probably not relevant - and from my experience I'll finally struggle with them
- The framework seems to have interesting ecommerce building blocks: [Sylius bundles](http://sylius.org) and [Vespolina bundles](http://vespolina.org)

What I am looking for is some feedback about those bundles, preferably from people who run them in production:

- Is there one suite of bundles arguably better than the other (stability, features)?
- Can they be mixed easily? (I saw on a Sylius presentation that some Vespolina bundles could be used within)
- How does the community respond to bug reports, support requests and new features development?
- And anything that can contribute to a comparison between those bundles

And finally, are there some other Symfony2 ecommerce initiatives that I've missed?

Of course I've been doing my research, and I can not seem to find any interesting comparison between those bundles.

About the site:

- Virtual products (songs) are sold
- French site, so VAT rules for France
- Mobile friendly

Comment: The best way to find out more about the bundles is on Freenode IRC in #vespolina and #sylius-dev. Personal opinion: Your requirements aren't toooo advanced..Sylius will do the job and is at a stage where you can use it (you have to put a lot more work into Vespolina).

Comment: I would advice sylius too, it will do the job.

Comment: I've added an update review for 2016 below.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**TLDR**

If you are going to develop an ecommerce website with symfony right now ( as of 2013-05-26 ) and you want to make use of existing bundles/implementations...

*Go for Sylius!*

**Why?**

*Vespolina*

Vespolina has received some attention when first announced as it claimed to be the first ecommerce solution for symfony2 but it's really more or less dead by now.

Even their [demo](http://try.vespolina.org/) page has only worked for me like 1/4 times. ( tried to add a product to the basket ... 404 )

There is no more active development and the documentation is [horrbile](https://github.com/vespolina/vespolina-docs/commits/master).
(last commit Sep 2012).

The repositories might still be a valuable source for inspiration in some cases though.

*Sylius*

Sylius has recently been [aquired](http://sylius.com/news/the-story-of-an-ecommerce-for-symfony2) by KnpLabs. For those who don't know ... KnpLabs runs:

- [knpbundles.com](http://knpbundles.com/) ( aka THE definite source for information about available bundles )
- the [KnpUniversity](http://knpuniversity.com/) ( aka the currently best Screencast provider for symfony2 ).

Ryan Weaver - symfony [core](https://github.com/symfony?tab=members) member & Lead author of the official Symfony2 doc - is one of the Knp guys.

Those guys definitely know what they do. Their [open source contributions](https://github.com/KnpLabs) are of outstanding quality and their bundles ( KnpMenuBundle, KnpPaginatorBundle, KnpGaufretteBundle ) are widely used throughout the community.

They are driving the Sylius project into the right direction. Development is quite active and there are already sites using Sylius in production. ( i.e. [sommelier-prive.de](http://www.sommelier-prive.de) was built with Sylius )

Comment: Thanks @nifr, you pretty well summed up the info I got from my own research.

Comment: It's not true that Sylius is aquired by KnpLabs. See here: http://knplabs.com/blog/2013/08/13/sylius-enterprise-services/

Comment: Oh ... that's pretty sad! it would be interesting to know the background for Pawel's decision to continue the development on his own :/ The article on sylius.org really stated *"aquired"* and not just a collaboration back then when i wrote this answer as far as i can remember. It seems to be offline by now ... I'll update the answer soon. Thanks for pointing that out @JakubZalas.

Answer (score 20):

**-- UPDATE 2016 --**

This is an updated answer, for all 2016 readers.

## Elcodi

Elcodi is a set of PHP Components that cover most of E-commerce needs, with their Bundles for Symfony, and a full-stack E-commerce project called Bamboo using these Bundles.

This project is meant to be a great option for pragmatic developers that need an E-commerce platform as fast as possible with the possibility of overriding every single part of the application as soon as they need it.

It has a good documentation (growing through releases and with new adopters) and offers a very specific philosophy of how a Symfony project should be seen and executed.

- [Elcodi Website](http://elcodi.io)
- [Elcodi Repository](https://github.com/elcodi/elcodi)
- [Bamboo Repository](https://github.com/elcodi/bamboo)
- [Elcodi Docs](http://elcodi.io/docs)
- [Elcodi Demo](http://bamboo.elcodi.io)

The project was born in March of 2014 and is actually stable. It has as well a clear roadmap for the next months. It covers some topics like Plugins and Templates, and is based on a clean Event-Driven Architecture.
It also has an active community in Gitter, so the project evolves day by day.

- [Elcodi Community Room](http://gitter.im/elcodi/elcodi)

The project is compatible with Symfony3.

## Sylius

Sylius is a project with more than 4 years. Mature and with a great community. This project offers a set of PHP Components and Symfony Bundles, offering a lot of E-commerce related features.

The project itself offers a Bundle for a store and an admin panel using these features.

- [Sylius Website](http://sylius.org)
- [Sylius Repository](http://github.com/sylius/sylius)
- [Sylius Docs](http://docs.sylius.org)
- [Sylius Demo](http://demo.sylius.org)

The project was born in September of 2011 and is not stable. The project has a good community that meet in its Gitter channel.

- [Sylius Community Room](https://gitter.im/sylius/sylius)

The project is still not compatible with Symfony3.

## Thelia2

Thelia2 is a Symfony-based full-stack project that covers some E-commerce related needs. The project is quite mature and is now on its second version.

As said, the project is full-stack, so doesn't really split between boundaries. Can be very useful for a monolithic projects (like have been covered until now projects like Prestashop or Magento).

- [Thelia Website](http://thelia.net)
- [Thelia Repository](https://github.com/thelia/thelia)
- [Thelia Docs](http://doc.thelia.net/)
- [Thelia Demo](http://demo-v2.thelia.net/)

The project was born in October 2012.
Thelia has not yet a Gitter community (or similar).
The project is not compatible with Symfony3. Indeed is only compatible with Symfony 2.3.

Some other options, including smaller projects and non e-commerce focused projects:

- [Sonata E-commerce](https://github.com/sonata-project/ecommerce)
- [ORO Commerce](https://github.com/orocommerce/orocommerce-application)
- [Aimeos](https://github.com/aimeos)
- [WellCommerce](https://github.com/WellCommerce/WellCommerce)

Non options, including non-maintained projects:

- [Vespolina](https://github.com/vespolina)
- [Leaphly](https://github.com/leaphly)

Comment: Sylius now supports SF3.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for Sylius too. There are few more solutions btw https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/bfcc794c1de2d7e0c482.

Comment: what about sonata? is that too outdated? I am having too many issues trying to setup Sylius, I am wondering if i should start looking into other ecommerce bundles.

Answer (score -1):

If your are looking to combine e-commerce and Symfony 2, Iet’s have a look at **[Thelia](http://thelia.net)**. It’s a new e-commerce solution based on Symfony 2 components. 
The stable version released in April 2014. 
Thelia uses the following Symfony 2 components : Config, Dependency injection, Http Kernel, Form, Event dispatcher… 
Thelia also complies with PSR norms.

The solution is constantly evolving, the roadmap is quite long !